# Op-amp circuit oscillation

Tags: operational-amplifier

The ideal op-amp is connected to a power source \$V_s\$ at t = 0. Initial charge on the capacitor is 0. 
Then it is given that \$V_{OUT}\$ swings to positive value and \$V^-\$ starts increasing. \$V^-\$ increases till \$V_{TH}\$  and then starts decreasing, till it reaches \$-V_{TH}\$ and starts increasing again. Thus it is a periodic cycle with oscillations between \$V_{TH}\$  and \$-V_{TH}\$. \$V_{TH}\$ is to be determined along with the oscillation period.\

I wrote the following two equation for the op-amp terminals
$$V^+ = \frac{R_3V_{OUT}}{R_2+R_3} \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; V^- = V_C \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \dot{V_C} = \frac{1}{R_1C}(V_{OUT}-V_C)$$
And since op amp is ideal \$V^- = V^+\$ at all times. 
What I could not understand was how would \$V^-\$ reach to a threshold voltage? Because after the capacitor voltage reaches \$V_{TH}\$, when it starts to decrease, the current across \$R_1\$ will become 0 momentarily, before switching direction. At that moment \$V^- = V_{OUT}\$; which will violate the equation of positive terminal.
[image]

Comment: "*And since op amp is ideal V−=V+ at all times.*" This may **not** be applicable for circuits with positive feedback where the opamp is purposefully driven to saturation.

Comment: Since the op amp is ideal, \$V_{out}\$ swings from \$+V_S\$ to \$-V_s\$ **instantly** when \$V_C\$ reaches \$V_{TH}\$ and exceeds it by an infinitesimally small amount. So a zero current condition doesn't occur in the *ideal* circuit. Current also switches from one direction to the other direction instantly without passing through the zero current condition.

Comment: Current is "through" and not across. Voltage is "across".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of virtual ground cannot be applied to this circuit. It is applicable only to circuits where the net opamp circuit is in negative feedback mode and it is the negative feedback which ensures that \$V- = V+\$. Here the opamp circuit has positive feedback via R2 and R3. The output of the opamp is driven to saturation due to this positive feedback. Hence \$V-\$ need not always equal \$V+\$.

"Because after the capacitor voltage reaches VTH, when it starts to decrease". The terminology "starts to decrease" can only be applied to a real opamp with finite slew rate. For an ideal opamp with *infinite slew rate*, the output instantly changes from \$V_s\$ to \$-V_s\$ (It doesn't go *through* zero voltage). So there is no time instant where the current is zero. Current also instantly changes sign.

### Before switching

\$V^+ = +V_{TH} > V_C = V^-\$. So \$V_o = +V_s\$. (consistent set of eqns)

current \$I = (V_s - V_C)/R\$. and \$V_C \rightarrow V_{TH}\$.

### Instantly after switching

\$V_C = V^- > V^+\$. So \$V_o = -V_s\$. So \$V^+ = -V_{TH}\$. (consistent set of eqns)

\$I = (-V_s - V_C)/R\$.
i.e. current is non zero always.

With ideal components which can have infinite slew rate and discontinuous outputs, the intuition breaks down and you have to rely on which set of equations are consistent and which are not. In your case current = 0 assumption leads to a set of inconsistent equations (as you have noticed). That means that current doesn't reach such a condition.